# How 32 bit pointer ( on 32 bit computer ) can search the data in 1 TB of hard disk ?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a 32 bit computer hence , I can refer at most 4 GB of different addresses . Now , CPU wants some data and it will generate some physical address ( suppose the data is some file ) and the data ( file ) is only stored in ROM , not in registers , cache or RAM . Now , how will be the data ( file ) searched . ( We have provided the path of the file ) . And the data search in ROM can be random ?

Comment: What exactly is the `c++` question here?

Comment: Stream size types are usually 64-bit, nowadays  (even on a 32 bit machine)

Comment: There is the kernel of a useful question here, let's help the OP improve it rather than close it.  Like many beginners, there is confusion about how RAM is addressed, and how files are referenced.  This is a good opportunity to clarify the difference.

Comment: The OS might and probably does organize the hard drive into multiple big sections. Even if you hard drive has 1TB of addressable memory, it's probably organized into bigger chunks (maybe 4kb per chunk) first, then store another offset into the chunk

Comment: Files on a disk are accessed differently than RAM. The specifics are complicated and there are many different implementations. The wikipedia article on [File system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) might answer some of your questions.

Comment: `C++` mandates types we can use to store file stream offsets: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/streamoff

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you don't load a big file at once, but part for part.

Also on 32bit computers, the access methods to files can take 64bit values as file position pointers.